# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm doing a course with Primefaces jsf, hibernate, maven. I got that part where I run the xhtml (.faces), researched on the Internet told me to delete persistence-api but did not work, copy the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api1.0.1.Final to jre / lib / ext also did not work, what is causing this error and how can I solve it?

erro below

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1866)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:765)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3406)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1334)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
    at com.mycompany.jsf_maven.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    at com.mycompany.jsf_maven.util.PhaseListenerJsf.beforePhase(PhaseListenerJsf.java:15)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>br.com.Jsf_Maven</groupId>
<artifactId>Jsf_Maven</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Jsf_Maven</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <themes.version>1.0.8</themes.version>
    <jsf.version>2.1.7</jsf.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.9</mysql.version>
    <groovy-all.version>1.7.5</groovy-all.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>   
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>

    <!-- PRIMEFACES REPOSITORY -->
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>        

    <!-- FACELETS TAGLIBRARIES REPOSITORY -->

    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.security.taglibs.facelets</id>
        <url>http://spring-security-facelets-taglib.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- REPOSITÓRIO DA AOP ALLIANCE -->
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- REPOSITÓRIO DO JASPER REPORTS -->        
    <repository>
        <id>jasperreports</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>  

</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- || DEPENDÊNCIAS DO JAVA SERVER FACES || -->                        
    <!-- ############## JSF-API ################ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############## JSF-IMPL ############### -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ################ JSTL ################# -->
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>  
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <!-- ############ SERVLET-API ############## --> 
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>  
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>  
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############## JSP-API ################ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ##### DEPENDÊNCIAS DO PRIMEFACES ##### -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ######## TEMAS DO PRIMEFACES ######### -->        
    <dependency>              
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>              
        <version>${themes.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>le-frog</artifactId>  
        <version>${themes.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>sam</artifactId>  
        <version>${themes.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>pepper-grinder</artifactId>  
        <version>${themes.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>smoothness</artifactId>  
        <version>${themes.version}</version> 
    </dependency>        

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>ui-lightness</artifactId>  
        <version>${themes.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>south-street</artifactId>  
        <version>${themes.version}</version> 
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- |||||| DEPENDÊNCIAS DO HIBERNATE |||||| -->

    <!-- ########### HIBERNATE-C3P0 ############ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############### C3P0 ################## -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ########### HIBERNATE CORE ############ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>            
    </dependency>

    <!-- ########### HIBERNATE ANTLR ########### -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ######### COMMONS-COLLECTIONS ######### -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############### DOM4J ################# -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- #### HIBERNATE-COMMONS-ANNOTATIONS #### -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############# HIBERNATE-JPA ########### -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############## JAVASSIST ############## -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############ JBOSS-LOGGING ############ -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ######## JBOSS-TRANSACTION-API ######## -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>      

    <!-- ##### JPA-HIBERNATE-ENTITYMANAGER ##### -->                        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>            
    </dependency>

    <!-- ########## HIBERNATE-EHCACHE ########## -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############ EHCACHE-CORE ############# -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>            
    <!-- |||| DEPENDÊNCIAS DO hibernate |||| -->        

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



    <!-- |||| DEPENDÊNCIAS DO MYSQL DRIVER  |||| -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- |||| DEPENDÊNCIAS DO SPRING-SECURITY || -->  

    <!-- ### FACELETS-TAGLIB-JSF2.0-SPRING-3 ### -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ####### SPRING-SECURITY-TAGLIBS ####### -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>            

    <!-- ####### SPRING-SECURITY-CONFIG ######## -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ######## SPRING-SECURITY-CORE ######### -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ######### SPRING-SECURITY-WEB ######### -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ||| DEPENDÊNCIAS DO SPRING FRAMEWORK |||-->          
    <!-- ############# SPRING-ASM ############## -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############ SPRING-BEANS ############# -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ########### SPRING-CONTEXT ############ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############# SPRING-CORE ############# -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ########## SPRING-EXPRESSION ########## -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############# SPRING-JDBC ############# -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>        

    <!-- ############## SPRING-TX ############## -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############# SPRING-WEB ############# -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>    

    <!-- ############# SPRING-AOP ############# -->    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############ AOP-ALLIANCE ############ -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ############ AOP-ALLIANCE ############ -->
    <dependency>            
        <groupId>org.aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- ||||||| DEPENDÊNCIAS DO J-UNIT |||||||| -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>         
</build>
   </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethod` occurs due to non existence of the method over the runtime or the **conflict** with libraries mean when we have something like this:

`org.hibernate.javax.persistence-1.0`
`org.hibernate.javax.persistence-1.0.1`

So,In runtime compiler doesn't know to load `orphanRemoval` from It is located on both `org.hibernate.javax.persistence` 1.0 and 1.0.1  jars  , So check other dependencies if they have **an already built in `org.hibernate.javax.persistence`**

In that case : you should provide an exclusion a maven dependency feature
But that under one condition if that versions differs so for ex:

`hibernate-entitymanager` has an inner `org.hibernate.javax.persistence` say its version is 1.0.0

and in same time you include `org.hibernate.javax.persistence` with version 1.0.1 (if that version was 1.0.0 so That would be OK cause it all will be one jar at last despite multiplicity )

so this will make conflict with your dependency so two solutions are here :

You either check that `org.hibernate.javax.persistence` in all dependencies refers same version or you execlude versions which can make conflicts in that case you exclude `org.hibernate.javax.persistence` from `hibernate-entitymanager`

// this is only one example

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

You can dig in if other dependencies actually contain `org.hibernate.javax.persistence` on board thrugh that link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/usages

another simple solution is to upgrade all your dependencies specially hibernate and spring to the latest ones sure they will point to `org.hibernate.javax.persistence-1.0.1`

Hope that helped :)